# Windows 10: Start menu right-click is broken

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu, right-click

I clean installed Windows 10 Pro today and upgraded to Education edition(because that's the licence I had).

However, after a while of installing a few programs I need, something happened to the start menu. When I right click any live tile or executable it only shows one option, "more", which has a submenu with 3 or 4 options(pin to taskbar, Run as administrator, Open file locator) or (Turn live tile off, pin to taskbar, Rate and review, Share). There is no option at all for resize, or pin to start menu, or uninstall.

The option to pin to start menu is also gone from the right-click menu of file explorer. And also, I can't even drag and drop things into start menu.

Any solution I tried did nothing to solve the problem so far.

Comment: Registry edit in this page should help: [Personalize Settings Says "Some settings are managed by your organization](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/personalize-some-settings-managed-organization/)

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve the problem, and the registry fix that I used is this one.

[[Fix] Pin to Start Option Missing in Windows 10](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/pin-to-start-missing-windows/)

Comment: This is a link-only answer. If the link goes bad, the answer will be useless. Please [edit] it to include essential parts of the solution, then provide a link to original source.